# Qiskit, possible to manipulate mid-circuit measurement outcomes?

Tags: qiskit, error-correction, simulation, fault-tolerance, error-mitigation

I'm currently coding up an error correction gadget using qiskit.
The one I'm doing now is 7-qubit Steane code with Steane's error correction gadget, in which the ancilla qubits are measured and then the measurement outcomes are multiplied by the parity check matrix H. The three-bit outcome is the syndrome.

Since I want to put this EC gadget in a larger circuit, I want to do mid-circuit measurement and apply gates according to the syndrome. I'm aware I can achieve such a conditional operation by using `c_if` in qiskit. But I'm not sure how to multiply the outcome by H and then do conditional operation.

How do I do this or how can I get around this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiply the outcome by H", exactly?

Comment: @MicheleAmoretti Hi I want to do a matrix-vector product. H being the parity check matrix, v being the 7 bit measurement outcome